# Modifying an Excel VBA Script to Work in Word

Tags: bash, vba, excel, ms-word

I have the following VBA code:

```vb
Sub test2()
    Dim w1 As Worksheet
    Dim w2 As Worksheet

    Dim k As Long

    Dim c As Range
    Dim d As Range
    Dim strFA As String

    Set w1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set w2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

    w2.Cells.Clear
    k = 1

    With w1.Range("A:A")
        Set c = .Cells.Find("FirstThing", After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), lookat:=xlWhole)
        strFA = ""
        While Not c Is Nothing And strFA <> c.Address
            If strFA = "" Then strFA = c.Address
            If IsError(Application.Match(c.Offset(0, 1).value, w2.Range("A:A"), False)) Then
                Set d = .Cells.Find("SecondThing", c, , xlWhole)
                w2.Range("A" & k).value = c.Offset(1, 0).value
                w2.Range("B" & k).value = d.Offset(0, 1).value
                k = k + 1
            End If
            Set c = .Cells.Find("FirstThing", After:=c, lookat:=xlWhole)
        Wend
    End With

End Sub
```

The code works essentially like this:

1. Look through Sheet1 for a certain phrase.
2. Once the phrase is found, place the value from the cell one row over in Sheet2
3. Search for a second phrase.
4. Place the value from the cell one row over in the cell beside the other value in Sheet2
5. Repeat

Now.  I have the same data that, don't ask me why, is in .doc files.  I'd like to create something similar to this code that will go through and look for the first phrase, and place the next n characters in an Excel sheet, and then look for the second phrase and place the next m characters in the row beside the cell housing the previous n characters.

I'm not sure whether it's better to do this with a bash script or whether it's possible to do this with VBA, so I've attached both as tags.

Comment: I'm not sure you could edit a doc file using a stream editor like sed. Well I'll wait and see,, :)

Comment: Convert the data to excel?

Comment: @Christmas007 Do you know of an easy way to do this?

Comment: you cant reuse this code, parse directly a word document is a bad idea. For me, you sould use the ActiveDocument.Content.Text

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to be: "I'm not sure whether it's better to do this with a bash script or whether it's possible to do this with VBA"

The answer to that is: You'd need VBA, especially since this is a *.doc file - docx would be a different matter.

In order to figure out what that is, start by trying to do the task manually in Word. More specifically, how to use Word's "Find" functionality. When you get that figured out, record those actions in a macro to get the starting point for your syntax. The code on the Excel side for writing the data across will essentially stay the same.

You'll also need to decide where the code should reside: in Word or in Excel. That will mean researching how to run the other application from within the one you choose - lots of examples here on SO and on the Internet...